# How do I display image title in "Manage Display"?

Tags: 7, nodes

How do I display image title in "Manage Display"?

I have add title in my image.　But it is not showing in article.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image title is a part of the image field not the main node title. So, you can't see the image title field under manage display.